# Add action to item in UITabBar in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I made an iOS app with Xcode and Swift. There're multiple `UIViewControllers` managed by one `UITabBarController` with an `UITabBar`. I can switch the ViewControllers with the items in the UITabBar.

Is there a way to add an action to the items in the TabBar, e.g. when the user makes a long press or uses 3d touch?

In my case, I want to reload the UIWebView content when the user makes a long or hard press.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom UITabBarController and handle action to items.

In your custom UITabBarController you can do like:

```
//tag values of navigation controllers are set in storyboard
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.tag {
        case 0:
        //Perform any action on item

        case 1:
        //open application

        default:
            break
    }

}
```

Comment: @David If this helped you please mark it as correct.

Comment: But I don't want to use custom `UITabBarController`.